# Merging jUnit coverage reports with EclEMMA plugin

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, emma, eclemma

I am measuring the code coverage in my project using the ***EclEmma*** plugin for Eclipse. This involves running the coverage for the whole project. But due to some dependency issues tests in some packages are failing altogether. When the coverage for these package is taken individually, the tests run properly and the package is showing the coverage correctly.

Is it possible to get a Coverage report, by running the coverage for each package separately and then merging these reports into one.

Or Alternatively, are there any other free plugins which offer the above capability.

Note: Modifying the test methods to remove the dependency may not be possible due to logical and size constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I shifted to IDEA, but I seem to recall that there was an option (as in "button in the EclEMMA view") to merge several coverage runs.

A visit to http://www.eclemma.org/ confirms this - look for "Merge Sessions". Also:

- http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/sessions.html and
- http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/coverageview.html

It is the button to the right of the "double-X" *Remove all sessions* button.

Cheers,